# Docker build: Running setup.py install for mariadb fails

Tags: python, docker, mariadb, connector

I'm building a **docker image for python code** that must **connect with a remote MariaDB server**. I was able to run this locally after some trial and error, but to make the installation on a remote (virtual) server easier, I really would like the solution to work too with a docker image.

As soon as I use an older alpine version < 3.11, using a lower version results in compatibility issue:

```
MariaDB Connector/Python requires MariaDB Connector/C >= 3.1.5, found version 3.0.10
```

Different python versions also doesn't seem to work.

My *Dockerfile*:

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache mariadb-dev build-base
RUN pip install mariadb
```

Console output:

```
> docker build . -t dockerpython
Sending build context to Docker daemon  137.5MB
Step 1/7 : FROM python:3.6-alpine3.12
3.6-alpine3.12: Pulling from library/python
Digest: sha256:c228fcf0064d5595b4c7aab92b68598917383fe066dc5e17d2e426b0395c7848
Status: Downloaded newer image for python:3.6-alpine3.12
 ---> 176f50d88b04
Step 2/7 : RUN apk add --no-cache mariadb-dev build-base
 ---> Using cache
 ---> afd8f9e92e7f
Step 3/7 : RUN pip install mariadb
 ---> Running in 887a7e3ea2f2
Collecting mariadb
  Downloading mariadb-1.0.3.tar.gz (66 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: mariadb
  Building wheel for mariadb (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for mariadb (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-x63w3ma6/mariadb/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-x63w3ma6/mariadb/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-kxbxgt6f
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-x63w3ma6/mariadb/
  Complete output (29 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mariadb
  copying mariadb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mariadb
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mariadb/constants
  copying mariadb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mariadb/constants
  copying mariadb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mariadb/constants
  copying mariadb/constants/INDICATOR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mariadb/constants
  copying mariadb/constants/CURSOR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mariadb/constants
  copying mariadb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mariadb/constants
  running build_ext
  building 'mariadb._mariadb' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/mariadb
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -DTHREAD_STACK_SIZE=0x100000 -fPIC -DPY_MARIADB_MAJOR_VERSION=1 -DPY_MARIADB_MINOR_VERSION=0 -DPY_MARIADB_PATCH_VERSION=3 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/mysql -I./include -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -c mariadb/mariadb.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/mariadb/mariadb.o -DDEFAULT_PLUGINS_SUBDIR="/usr/lib/mariadb/plugin"
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -DTHREAD_STACK_SIZE=0x100000 -fPIC -DPY_MARIADB_MAJOR_VERSION=1 -DPY_MARIADB_MINOR_VERSION=0 -DPY_MARIADB_PATCH_VERSION=3 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/mysql -I./include -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -c mariadb/mariadb_connection.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/mariadb/mariadb_connection.o -DDEFAULT_PLUGINS_SUBDIR="/usr/lib/mariadb/plugin"
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -DTHREAD_STACK_SIZE=0x100000 -fPIC -DPY_MARIADB_MAJOR_VERSION=1 -DPY_MARIADB_MINOR_VERSION=0 -DPY_MARIADB_PATCH_VERSION=3 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/mysql -I./include -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -c mariadb/mariadb_exception.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/mariadb/mariadb_exception.o -DDEFAULT_PLUGINS_SUBDIR="/usr/lib/mariadb/plugin"
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -DTHREAD_STACK_SIZE=0x100000 -fPIC -DPY_MARIADB_MAJOR_VERSION=1 -DPY_MARIADB_MINOR_VERSION=0 -DPY_MARIADB_PATCH_VERSION=3 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/mysql -I./include -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -c mariadb/mariadb_cursor.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/mariadb/mariadb_cursor.o -DDEFAULT_PLUGINS_SUBDIR="/usr/lib/mariadb/plugin"
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -DTHREAD_STACK_SIZE=0x100000 -fPIC -DPY_MARIADB_MAJOR_VERSION=1 -DPY_MARIADB_MINOR_VERSION=0 -DPY_MARIADB_PATCH_VERSION=3 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/mysql -I./include -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -c mariadb/mariadb_codecs.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/mariadb/mariadb_codecs.o -DDEFAULT_PLUGINS_SUBDIR="/usr/lib/mariadb/plugin"
  mariadb/mariadb_codecs.c: In function 'my_strtoull':
  mariadb/mariadb_codecs.c:148:15: error: 'ULONG_LONG_MAX' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'ULLONG_MAX'?
    148 |     if (val > ULONG_LONG_MAX /10 || val*10 > ULONG_LONG_MAX - (*p - '0'))
        |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        |               ULLONG_MAX
  mariadb/mariadb_codecs.c:148:15: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mariadb
...
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install mariadb' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filed (and already fixed) that bug in [MariaDB's ticket system](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/CONPY-125)

The fix will be available in MariaDB Connector/Python 1.0.4 (which will be likely available via pypi.org by end of this week).

As a workaround you can download latest version from [github repository](https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-python) and build it manually, or you could try (I didn't test it)

```
export CFLAGS=-D_GNU_SOURCE=1
pip3 install mariadb
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try it again later this week.

Comment: Fyi: Version 1.0.4 is now available on pypi.org

Comment: Awesome! It has built successfully.
Thank you very much for the lightning fast fix!

Answer (score 0):

Before installing the mariadb you need to install a few dependencies.

*MariaDB version 10.2* -- `sudo apt-get install -y libmariadb-dev`

*MariaDB version 10.3* -- `sudo apt-get install -y libmariadb-dev-compat`

And rather than going with alpine or python base images, you can use `debian:slim` base image.